# Python (numpy): drop columns by index

Tags: python, numpy

I've got a numpy array and would like to remove some columns based on index. Is there an in-built function for it or some elegant way for such an operation?

Something like:

```
arr = [234, 235, 23, 6, 3, 6, 23]
elim = [3, 5, 6]

arr = arr.drop[elim]

output: [234, 235, 23, 3]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `numpy.delete`, it will return a new array:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([234, 235, 23, 6, 3, 6, 23])
elim = [3, 5, 6]
np.delete(arr, elim)
```